# Can't import chainlink using web3j

Tags: solidity, blockchain, web3j, chainlink

I am making simple contract using AndroidStudio and Java.In my contract i am using
import statement:

```
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

but when i try to generate Java version of my contract in POwerShell
i am getting this error in powerShell
[image]

my contract:

```
   //SPDX-License-Identifier: NULL

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract FundMe{

mapping(address => uint256) public adressToAmountFunded;
address[] public funders;
address public owner;

constructor()public{
    owner = msg.sender;
}

function fund() public payable{
    uint256 minUsd = 5 *10**18;
    require(getConversionRate(msg.value) >= minUsd, "Nedovoljno MATIC coina!");
    adressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    funders.push(msg.sender);
}  

function getVersion() public view returns (uint256){
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xd0D5e3DB44DE05E9F294BB0a3bEEaF030DE24Ada);
    return priceFeed.version();
}
 
function getPrice() public view returns(uint256){
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xd0D5e3DB44DE05E9F294BB0a3bEEaF030DE24Ada);
    (,int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    return  uint256(answer * 10000000000);
      
}
  function getConversionRate(uint256 ethAmount) public view returns (uint256){
        uint256 ethPrice = getPrice();
        uint256 ethAmountInUsd = (ethPrice * ethAmount) / 10**18;
        // the actual ETH/USD conversation rate, after adjusting the extra 0s.
        return ethAmountInUsd;
     
    }

    modifier OnlyOwner{
         require(msg.sender == owner,"Pogresan Korisnik");
         _;
    }

    function withDraw() public OnlyOwner payable{
    
       payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
       //iterate through all the mappings and make them 0
        //since all the deposited amount has been withdrawn
        for (uint256 funderIndex=0; funderIndex < funders.length; funderIndex++){
            address funder = funders[funderIndex];
            adressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0;
        }
        //funders array will be initialized to 0
        funders = new address[](0);
    }

  }
```

Comment: have you installed the chainlink library before trying to compile? https://docs.chain.link/docs/create-a-chainlinked-project/

Comment: @Harry Papacharissiou
 well after i installed a got ParserError: Source "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol" not found: File not found inside the base path or any of the include paths.

Comment: can you update your original question to include a screenshot of the folder structure of the folder that has your project. It should have a folder containing your imported modules

Comment: i gave up.. started to use truffle but thanks for help anyway :)